# Unable to show checked List View Item in the next Activity

Tags: java, android

I Have an `Activity` with a `ListView`. `ListView` row consist of 3 `TextView` and a `Checkbox`. I want to show the checked list item to another `activity`. I am using `Custom Adapter` that extends `Cursor Adapter`. here's my code for `Custom Adapter`

```
class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter /*implements Serializable*/{
private LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<String> selectedStrings = new ArrayList<>();
private String str;
TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;

public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simplecursorrowlayout, viewGroup, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context,final Cursor cursor) {
    tv1 =  view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv2 =  view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv3 =  view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tv1.setText(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(0)));
    tv2.setText(cursor.getString(1));
    tv3.setText(cursor.getString(2));
    final CheckBox checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.cBox);
    checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(((CheckBox)view).isChecked()){
                tv1.setText(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(0)));
                tv2.setText(cursor.getString(1));
            }
        }
    });
    /*checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if(b){
                //str=tv1.getText().toString()+"    "+tv2.getText().toString();
                //selectedStrings.add(str);
                tv1.setText(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(0)));
                tv2.setText(cursor.getString(1));
            }
        }
    });*/
 /*   Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),DisplayRecord.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Selected_Students",selectedStrings);
    context.startActivity(intent);*/
    }

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return true;
}

}
```

codes in comments are someother way that I've tried
When using `Intent` to pass all those data, my app hangs with a Black screen.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could expose the `selectedStrings` from the adapter.

```
class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter Serializable*/{

    public ArrayList<String> getSelectedStrings() {
        return selectedStrings;
    }
    // other existing codes
}
```

And then in the current activity, retrieve it when it's time to move to the next activity.

```
class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void displaySelectedItems() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayRecord.class);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Selected_Students", adapter.getSelectedStrings());
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    // other MyActivity's code
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Thanks a lot. This helped me.

Comment: another problem: I am not getting the list item of the same checkbox. it seems like it is randomly displaying any data from the listview. What Can I do?

Comment: Thank you. Although This helped me to send my data to another activity, But correct data is not sent to the next Activity. like if I am selecting checkbox of listview row 1 then it sends the data of some other row. Please help